# Cmdlet C# finalization

Tags: c#, powershell-cmdlet

So I'm working with cmdlets in C# and using a base cmdlet which derives from PSCmdlet.

Like this: Child <- Parent <- PSCmdlet.

We login to a system using methods in the Parent cmdlet. But sometimes things don't always go right with exceptions, crashes and so on. So it doesn't really logout properly.

My question is as follows:
Is there a method existing that I can implement/override in the Parent cmdlet that will run no matter what happens so that we properly can logout? Kind of like try finally. 
I have checked out EndProcessing() and StopProcessing() but they aren't really up to the task in unforeseen situations.

Edit: To clarify, there are multiple cmdlets and the situation is not just about login. There are multiple exceptions that can occur based on code and user-input.

Comment: Are the errors/exceptions preventable (code-wise, not end-user)? If so, then spend the time to correct them. Are the errors/exceptions due to user input? Then use try/catch/finally. You mentioned something like try/finally. Why does use of try/finally not work for your situation?

Comment: In some cases of the cmdlets we throw exceptions by design, e.g UnauthorizedException. 
We still want the exceptions that occur during execution of cmdlet.

Comment: Do these purposeful exceptions stop execution ?

Comment: Yes, they do stop the execution.

Comment: Is there a reason why Try-Catch would not work for this situation?

Comment: You could rethrow a caught exception depending on your needs/desires. Shouldn't stop you from using try-catch blocks...

Comment: But before considering rethrowing, think about whether you could achieve your goal by using multiple catch clauses filtering for different exception types in your try-catch structure (i.e., only catch the exception types you want to not leave/exit your cmdlet...)

Comment: Try-Catch will work, but it means a bigger job. Not to be lazy, but we were kind of hoping for a "finalize" method. 
So I'm gathering from the comments that really the only way to go is by doing try catch in each and every cmdlet.

Comment: You can implement `IDisposable`.

Comment: Please elaborate @PetSerAl :)

Comment: If cmdlet implement `IDisposable`, then PowerShell will use that implementation when it done with cmdlet.

Comment: it worked! That was awesome :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for my problem, as @PetSerAl suggested, was to implement IDisposable in the Parent class. 
Using Dispose() I could then add whatever methods needed to finalize the cmdlet no matter what happens.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a good case to use `Try-catch`:

```
try
{
    UserLogin();
    OtherMethod();
}
catch(UnauthorizedException au)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Unauthorized user... shutting down");
    //Closing Code...
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
catch(OtherException oe)
{
    //Closing Code...
    Environment.Exit(0);
}
...
```

Where you would (if not already) throw the `UnauthorizedException()` exception within `UserLogin()` or which ever method you are using to test credentials.

This concept can also be applied to the other areas of code that you are *expecting* exceptions to be thrown. If the exceptions are because of code not working properly, `Try-Catch` should not be used to suppress that error as it should be corrected. Exceptions/errors based off of User-Input could be wrapped with `Try-Catch`.

Comment: I clarified in my question that it's not just UnauthorizedException, but I see what you mean.

Comment: You would be able to `catch` filter as needed. Where `OtherException` should obviously be the name of the actual exception. Updated Answer